# IIS7.0, ASP.NET 4.0 and .NET 4.0 assembly loading problem

Tags: .net

I am experiencing a skmMenu.dll assembly loading issue on a Win 2008 R2 Server box. the following is what the debug output looks like once the request fails to my www.xxxxx.com/yy.aspx :
(using IE 8)

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'skmMenu' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
LOG: DisplayName = skmMenu, Version=2.2.4187.20308, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/inetpub/wwwroot/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
```

Running the web app from VS2010 works and the assembly gets found and loaded correctly: This is the log file output from Fusion Log Viewer once a fire up the web app from the IDE in debug mode:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = AMERICANBUS\apersson
LOG: DisplayName = skmMenu, Version=2.2.4187.20308, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/inetpub/wwwroot/NEWACES/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\inetpub\wwwroot\NEWACES\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\newaces\258eee81
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\newaces\258eee81
LOG: AppName = 3e3bc721
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\inetpub\wwwroot\NEWACES\web.config
```

I noticed that the IIS 7.0 / CRL is not resolving the web app root directory correctly as when I run the app from VS2010, hence I suspect it is not finding the dll in the first place. Look at the Inital Private Path difference in the two log outputs..? The site is open to anyone for access at this point. Using Virtual Directory, binding looks kosher to the IP address....
Is there a config setting in IIS 7.0 that I am missing here ? Anyone with an idea ?
Appreciate the input on this issue.

Thanks
Anders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you double check that file:///D:/inetpub/wwwroot/NEWACES/ is a virtual directory in IIS?

Try recreating the virtual directory.